# How can I chose dark theme for a specific window from terminal?

Tags: release-freya, themes

For example I want to chose a dark theme for PhpStorm http://screenshot3.seobit.ru/roma.2015.09.03___08:30:1441258219.png (header of PhpStorm)

phpstorm.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PhpStorm
Exec=/home/roma/Rarely/Programs/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.sh
Icon=/usr/share/icons/elementary-add/apps/48/phpstorm.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Develop;
```

Comment: But how to install "GTK Theme Variant Switcher" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "GTK Theme Variant Switcher".

Description:

> A small service which forces certain windows to use a specific Gtk theme variant. E.g. force dark window borders.

More info about installation and configuration on [GitHub](https://github.com/theblacklion/gtk-theme-variant-switcher).

Comment: You post has been flagged as "low quality" because of its length. Can you provide more detailed directions on how to get, install, and use this software?